# Having spaces in QGIS leaflet web map layer names?

Tags: qgis, qgis2leaf

When I export a QGIS project to a leaflet webmap using QGIS2Leaf, is there a way I can have my layer names display with spaces. So for example in the image I would like OffshoreSACS to display as Offshore SACs and LicensedblocksMay2015 as Licensed blocks May 2015 etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the index.html file that gets exported, at the bottom there is an entry :

```
legend.addTo(map);    
L.control.layers({},{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx},{collapsed:true}).addTo(map);
```

You can type in there whatever layer name you want to show up.

Comment: qgis2leaf has now been merged into qgis2web, which also exports to OpenLayers3. I will check whether spaces in layer names are reproduced in the layer list (they should be), and if not, I'll patch the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the QGIS plugin qgis2web. That preserves spaces in layer names in the Leaflet layer list.